# Изменение глобальных переменных из функции.

Tags: php

Приветствую. У меня есть файл с таким содержанием:

```
$text = "a";

function MyFunc(){

$GLOBALS['text'] = "b";

}
MyFunc();
include('путь');
```

Он инклудит файл c таким содержанием :

```
echo $text;
```

Вроде все логично. Но как не странно выводит "a". Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$text = "a";    
function MyFunc(){     
  global $text;   
  $text = "b";   
}   
MyFunc();   
include('путь');   
echo $text;
```

Попробуйте так

Comment: Дак разницы нету. Тут только подход другой. Ибо у меня мы напрямую из массива глобальных переменных меняем значение , а тут сначала глобальную переменную берем и потом меняем ^^.